# Fixed header table wont work with Material Design

Tags: html, html-table, header, fixed, material-design-lite

I am using Google Material Design and trying to get a big table to work with a fixed header and a fixed first column. 
The problem appears to be with the material design css because if I try the plugins on simple tables and imported js files it works just fine. As soon as I include the CSS everything goes to hell.

I have tried multiple fixed-header and/or fixed-column plugins and also many of the solutions I found on stackoverflow and other websites. None of them work.

it is a simple html table (`<table class="mdl-data-table">`) with all the usual tags, that is thead, tbody, tr, td etc.

I am looking for a solution or plugin that works in combination with Google Material Design Tables, that will fix the first row to the top and the first column to the left side of the screen when I scroll in the table.

Comment: Show code please. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for guidelines